# Passing data from one fragment to another (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a project with 2 fragments. I am looking to pass an iterable from the first fragment to the second. Using navArgs is not an option, since it makes the program crash. Bundle seems to only work with primary data types. Is there a way to go about it, without using some super hacky solution, like passing a string of all the data separated by commas as a string?

Comment: Post your code here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern way to do this is with a `ViewModel` ([here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) and [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) or with the `FragmentResult` API (last link). Otherwise you're looking at doing it manually through the parent `Activity` - call a function on the `Activity` that passes your data to the *other* `Fragment`, that kind of thing.

If these `Fragments` are in separate `Activities` then you're looking at making your data `Parcelable` so it can go in a `Bundle`, or serialisation (e.g. the [Kotlin Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library) so you can put it in a `Bundle` as a `String`, or persist it on disk so you can load it from the next `Activity`. Serialisation libraries are a robust way of turning objects and data into a stream of text (and other formats if you like) but there's nothing wrong with a `String` and some separator character if it's all you need, e.g. storing a list of indices or IDs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared view model.
In your first fragment:

```
<code>class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.setData(yourIterable)
    }
}
```

```
</code>
In your second fragment: 
<code>class SecondFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        val data = viewModel.getData()
    }
}
```

```
</code>
And your <code>SharedViewModel</code>: 
<code>class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _data
```